# Конфликт datepicker и fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox

Приветствую! При помещении datepicker в fancybox происходит конфликт событий и переключение месяца листает fancybox.
 
**HTML:**

```
<a href="#fansy">Open</a>
<div id="fansy">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });

    $("a").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/n05xd1xh/1/
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: А можно сценарий? С описание ожидаемого и реального события.

Comment: @Vartlok Извините, а как его просмотреть? Подскажите, если не сложно.

Comment: Сценарий посмотреть? Это вы должны нам его сказать, что вы делаете и что вам не нравится в результате.

Answer (score 4):

Не вешайте *Fancybox* на все элементы `<a>`. Например задайте ссылкам, открывающим окно какое-нибудь имя класса. Иначе *Fancybox* начинает чудить со всеми ссылками в календаре.

Вот например так:

```
<a href="#fansy" class="fancy-open"></a>

$(".fancy-open").fancybox({
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n05xd1xh/2/)

Comment: Блин, точно. Спасибо большое!